# practical arithmetic in prime factorizations

Tags: arithmetic, primality-test, prime-factorization

I am quite adept at doing arithmetic mentally or on paper, but I know little about the relatively sophisticated stuff that software experts use to crunch numbers.  **My question is whether the following idea is frequently used by such experts.**

Say I'm trying to find the prime factorization of some immense number $N$, and I find that it's divisible by a bunch of small primes, e.g.
$$
N = 2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot3\cdot 7 \cdot19\cdot53\cdot79\cdots\cdots\cdots.
$$
I've still got a long way to go to get anywhere near $\sqrt{N}$, but then I notice that the quotient of $N$ by the product of the prime factors I've found so far has a square root just smaller than the biggest prime I've found so far. **So I draw this conclusion: That quotient is prime.**

Might this method of establishing primality be used in actual software?

Comment: You already know that N is not 2 but is divisible by 2, so N is not prime! But yes - if you have determined that (say) 5 does not divide N, then of course it won't divide any quotient of N. This is certainly well known and frequently used whenever it's required, but I would guess that breaking numbers into lots of primes isn't something that's often required.

Comment: @Billy : What exactly is the relevance of the conclusion of your first sentence, that $N$ is not prime?  That hardly seems worth saying.

Comment: Your question was "Might this *method of establishing primality* be used in actual software?". My answer: you have already established the non-primality of N. I answered the obvious question with an obvious answer, and then followed up with your other question (which is the question I think you *intended* to ask).

Comment: @Billy : I don't see that you've answered the question I intended to ask.  The question of whether $N$ is prime is not even hinted at in my posting as far as I can see.

Comment: What else did you mean by "establishing primality", then? More to the point, what did you intend to ask?

Comment: I think my question is clear, but maybe only if you read it.  You say you "then followed up with your other question (which is the question I think you intended to ask".  But what you "followed up with" is this: "but I would guess that breaking numbers into lots of primes isn't something that's often required."  I can't be sure what you mean by this, and I don't see how it addresses the question.

Comment: Michael, rather than being rude to me and accusing me of not reading your question, it is in your best interests to make your question clear. In particular, (a) "establishing primality" of a number you have *already established is not prime* is clearly not what you wanted to know, and (b) which "number-crunching experts" exactly are you talking about? This isn't just flippancy: if your question is "which techniques do people usually use to completely factorise numbers that are products of lots of small primes?", then you'd better make sure people actually *do* this.

Comment: @Billy : I don't think I've been rude.  I was not asking how to show that the number I called $N$ is prime, and I was not asking how to factor any number.  I was asking about a method of establishing the primality of the QUOTIENT of $N$ by the small prime factors that you've already found.

Comment: I'm afraid I really have no idea what you're asking. The method in question, regardless of whether you're talking about N or some quotient, is trial division. It is a primitive algorithm, used when the numbers in question are small or have small prime factors, or memory available is very limited, and not when they are large with large prime factors. Magma, Maple, Mathematica and MATLAB mostly use Miller-Rabin, though Mathematica uses trial division to a very limited extent. I am certain you know all this, though, because it's very easy to find online.

Comment: @Billy : Others seem to have understood, and I think my question is clearly expressed.  I think your mention of trial division really demonstrates that you're lost.

Comment: I know I'm lost. That's why I've asked you several times to rephrase your question. For the second time, please stop being so rude. I am, after all, still trying to understand the problem and help you. (But no, the method you have outlined above *is* trial division. You have divided N by a bunch of small factors until you hit a bound, using the uniqueness of prime factorisation along the way to sharpen the bound.)

Comment: OK, suppose I've found $N = 2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot3\cdot 7 \cdot19\cdot53\cdot79\cdots\cdots\cdots$, where the dots correspond to prime factors bigger than $79$.  Look at $N/(2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot3\cdot 7 \cdot19\cdot53\cdot79)$.  Suppose the square root of that number is a bit less than $79$.  One then concludes that that number is prime.  My question is whether inferring primality in just that way is a technique used in actual software.  (Certainly it is used when doing arithmetic by hand.)

Comment: Then the answer in my penultimate comment stands: this is trial division (call your quotient $M$; then you have shown that $M$ has no factors of 2, 3, 5, ..., 79 (this is how you constructed $M$ from $N$), and you've noted that $79 > \sqrt{M}$, so $M$ must be prime); and most commercial general-purpose mathematical software only attempts to find one factor, but it almost always uses more advanced tests, mostly the Miller-Rabin test, rather than trial division. If you want a different answer, I suspect it'll have to come from someone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All general-purpose factorization software does trial division by a (usually) very large list of small primes before switching to the heavy machinery.

[I say "general-purpose" factorization because there are special-purpose algorithms for cases where the target number is a semi-prime and very large.  See Number Field Sieve, for example.]

In the case you cite above, your trick is correct (of course) but I have never seen it used.  Instead what normally would happen is this: all small factors are divided out, as you indicated, and then the remaining number is submitted to a primality test.  The primality test can be slow if the remaining quotient $Q$ is large, but in your case it's not:  you suppose that $\sqrt{Q}$ is slightly smaller than the largest prime in your list.  In practice, the largest prime in the "small primes list" will be around, say, $2^{30}$.  This means $q \approx 2^{60}$ and a primality test (which is $O(n^3)$ for an $n$-bit number) will be very fast.  Your trick requires only a square-root (or even trickier: square the largest prime in your list and compare, which requires one multiplication), which is definitely faster but we're talking about milliseconds here.

**Note:** There is no denying that by-hand your idea is a very worthwhile step to take.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using trial division from a list of primes, you can certainly do that.  Assume I have a list of primes less than $1,000,000$.  Each time I find a factor, I divide it out of $N$ as many times as possible.  In your example, you would be down to $N/26729808$.  If this were less than $79^2$ you could conclude it is prime.  If I keep going through my list and get to the end, if the remaining number is less than $10^{12}$ it is prime.

Comment: Ross, I don't get your answer. You seem to be reiterating his idea rather than answering his question regarding the use of this technique in actual software.

Comment: @Fixee: Yes I am confirming that it works.

Comment: +1  However, I am somewhat concerned with the question of whether occasions to use this method arise in practice, so the answer is not complete.